# using Index Match in Excel to return wk nr and MAX sales?

Tags: excel

I have two columns in excel:

```
week nr | sales
1         111
2          xxx
..         ....
```

I wanted to know the MAX(function) for sales column and in the same time, it to retun the week nr with the MAX sales.

How can I write it returns the MAX sales together with the week nr?

I was thinking of Index-Match...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With week nr in column A and sales in column B

```
=MAX(B1:B10)&" in week "&INDEX(A1:A10,MATCH(MAX(B1:B10),B1:B10,0))
```

Adjust ranges to suit.